# Deja un ImageView Libre para Rotar y hacer Zoom

Tags: android, android-studio

me encuentro desarrollando una aplicación donde tengo un mapa en imagen grande que quiero colocar en un activity de mi aplicación, pero quiero que este se pueda rotar con los dedos y hacer zoom igual como si fuera google maps.

Por lo tanto la imagen saldría en tamaño original en el activity y yo la rotaría y haría zoom si deseo...

¿alguien me ayudar o donde buscar para hacerlo?

Comment: estas preguntas son cerradas porque se basa de opiniones. Te recomiendo que bajes la aplicación de la Play Store llamada **"librerías para desarrolladores"** ahí encontraras varias librerías que hacen lo que pides

Comment: no es una opinion, es como lo hago no se hacerlo!!!

Comment: hola Edwin, si te entiendo, por eso te recomendé bajarte esa app, te muestra la librería con su repositorio y ejemplo correspondiente, saludos

Comment: Hola amigo edwin, tienes elcodigo ya realizado? o intentas hacerlo desde 0

Comment: No, lo único que tengo es mi activity en blanco.. y quisiera colocar la imagen y que al mover los dedos pueda rotar la imagen y hacerle zoom.. pero aun no encuentro como lograrlo

Comment: Más o menos entiendo lo que quieres hacer, mostrar una imágen poder hacerle pinch para zoom, moverte entre ella y si haces el gesto de rotar que rote la imágen?

Comment: He econtrado está librería que tal te pueda ser de ayuda https://github.com/martinwithaar/PinchToZoom

Comment: Acabo de crear un visor simple si es de ayuda está aquí https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/63434/hacer-zoom-rotar-y-moverse-por-dentro-de-un-imageview-en-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edito:
Puede llamar `View.setRotation()`, `View.setPivotX()`, `View.setPivotY()`, `View.setScaleX()`, `View.setScaleY()`, `View.setTranslationX()` y `View.setTranslationY()` sobre tu ImageView.

Referencia: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

Acá un ejemplo que hace todo: http://codesfor.in/move-zoom-and-rotate-imageview-in-android/

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

*Respuesta vieja incorrecta:*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto puede ajustarse a lo que buscas...
la libreria se llama Crooper, te dejo el repositorio con su documentación: https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper

saludos

Comment: No, creo que no haz leído bien mi pregunta arriba. Adjunto subiré un gif de lo que quiero lograr..

Comment: Si, es lo que necesito.. Lo probare y te cuento.
Esto es lo que quiero lograr: https://im3.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-3-7566b78f0b.gif